# keyboard input meathods (ibus?) crashed, and icons randomly rearranging

Tags: keyboard, icons, security, ibus, malware

Well, I got another issue, and it's this: One day, a mysterious window randomly popped up after a while after login, and after doing some basic stuff and using Kazam, I rebooted, and my icons began perfectly aligning together, and I noticed "auto-align" was automatically on. The reason I'm saying about this is because I don't think I turned on that feature, and I'm worried it's because my system's compromised and that I'll have to reinstall. The only other thing that might've caused the auto-align thing to turn on was if I maybe clicked on it on accident, but I don't think I did that. Can somebody tell me what's happening? Do I have a virus? Help? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 with 4.2 kernel from wily in the trusty repositories. EDIT: Did the 4.2 kernel cause this? If so, phew. EDIT2: It wasn't auto-align because it's on by default. So crap.

Answer (score 0):

IBus is an Intelligent Input Bus. It is a new input framework for the Linux OS. It provides full featured and user friendly input method user interface. It also may help developers to develop input method easily.

Check the version of `ibus` library on repository:

```
apt-cache show ibus|grep "Version:"
```

Probably the version of `ibus` should be 1.5.10 of the kernel 4.2 of Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf. In this case there is already a bug recognized for your issue, as described below:

[IDEA-78860 Keyboard input sometimes is blocked when IBus is active](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860)

**Solution:**

Either upgrade IBus to version 1.5.11 or add `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` to your `~/.profile`, then restart a session.

Alternatively, you can turn off IBus at *System Settings | Language Support | Keyboard input method*.

Comment: Umm, keyboard input wasn't an issue, just a random error screen popped up, and icons randomly rearranged after booting again afterwards.

Comment: The different kernel might have contributed to it, though.